# Implementing IF statement on Oracle Database

Tags: database, oracle, if-statement

Im trying to implement an IF statement to run a query on my Oracle Database.

The expectation:
If the employee is called John, display the limited items(item1 and item2), if it's not John, display the complete list.

```
DECLARE
  employeeName STRING := 'John';
   
BEGIN
IF (employeeName = 'John') THEN
       (SELECT TableA.Table from Table where TableA.Table = 'Item1' OR TableA.Table = 'Item2');
ELSE 
       (SELECT TableA.Table from Table);
END IF;
END;
```

Here's the error output:

> Error report: ORA-06550: line 6, column 2: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol " " when expecting one of the following:
>
> ( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma    raise
> return select update while with 'an identifier'    'a double-quoted
> delimited-identifier' 'a bind variable' ""continue close current
> delete fetch lock insert open rollback    savepoint set sql execute
> commit forall merge pipe purge
> 06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>
> *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
>
> *Action:

What am I doing wrong? Forgive my ignorance on IF statements implemented on databases.

Comment: This is PL/SQL, you can't just embed SQL like that - you need to define what to do with the results (e.g. `SELECT .. INTO ..`).

Answer (score 0):

In your code,

- `table` is a reserved keyword. Use double quotes or a different identifier
- select is missing `into`.
- String is missing length

You can apply your condition in a single SQL and then, use a `for` loop to loop over the result set.

```
DECLARE
  employeeName varchar2(100) := 'John';

BEGIN
    for t in (select "table" from tablea 
              where "table" in ('item1', 'item2')
                    or employeename = 'john') loop
        dbms_output.put_line(t."table");
    end loop;
END;
/
```

Comment: table is being used as a generic name, my table has a different name called employees.employeeName.
Wouldnt a 'for' statement use more resources?

Comment: What is exactly is your goal? If it is achievable in a set based approach then definitely use SQL operations. If your goal warrants a procedural approach, then for is an OK approach. It's better combined with  BULK COLLECT and FORALL if suitable

Comment: so, if the employee is named John, who is the only intern, he gets a limited view of the employee list, if he's not John, he will be getting a complete list. If this can be achieved without using 'declare' it would be perfect.